# Examples of first and second order intentional systems

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Daniel Dennet says

> `A first-order intentional system has beliefs and desires (etc.) but no beliefs and desires about beliefs and desires. ...
>
> A second-order intentional system is more sophisticated; it has beliefs and desires (and no doubt other intentional states) about beliefs and desires (and other intentional states) - both those of others and its own'.

I'm not sure I completely understand the difference between first-order and second-order intentional systems.

What are examples of first-order and second-order intentional systems?

Comment: A remark: It's a curious example of how analytic "philosophy of mind" has finally come to appreciate and converge to - in extent - with what phenomenology was speaking out since early 20th century.

Comment: It seems clear.  A second-order system can stand-back and reflect on the first-order, Similar to the relationship between, say, physics and metaphysics. Also connected with the idea of HOTS or 'higher-order thoughts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume for the sake of argument a belief/ desire model of action explanation. Beliefs and desires combine to form intentions that lead to action in the typical case. Suppose I am a smoker : I want (desire) a pack of cigarettes and believe that the shop across the road sells cigarettes. I intend to buy a pack, cross the road and make my purchase accordingly.

Much of our intentional action is conducted at just this level. But now, suppose I hear about or start to take seriously the health risks of smoking. I still have my desire to smoke; that's part of a habit I can't discard easily. But I can now have a desire not to have the desire to smoke. I want to smoke but, reflecting on my desire to smoke, I want to get rid of that desire or to control it in some way. This is a desire about a desire; a desire that has for its object another desire. It's reasonably illuminating to call the desire about a desire a 'second-order' desire.

It doesn't, unlike a first-order desire such as the desire to smoke, immediately control my intentional actions. But it 'sits above' that first-order desire and is a desire to block or control it. We could call it a 'meta-desire'; Dennett calls it second order. Clear ? Or do you need further explanation ? If so, just ask.

[Note : I am aware that intentional action is often greatly more complex than I have depicted the desire to smoke and the intentions that result from it. I am deliberately simplifying in order to make the first-order, second-order distinction easier to grasp.]